# how do i set time and date as variable in a batch file?

Tags: date, batch-file, time

is it possible to set time /t and date /t as a VAR to use as

```
@echo off
set TIJD=time /T
set DATUM=date /T
echo %TIJD% %DATUM%
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

built-in env vars: `%TIME%` `%DATE%`

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%
```

if you need to further manipulate the values, you can assign these to other variables, to which you can do other operations:

```
setlocal
set D=%DATE%
set T=%TIME%
echo %D:~10,4%%D:~4,2%%D:~7,2%%T:~,2%%T:~3,2%%T:~6,2%
```

The output of `echo` above will be locale dependent, but for me yields, e.g., 20150117144508.

Answer (score 1):

```
set  TimeStr=%Time::= %
Echo TimeStr
```

takes out ilegal characters from Time (replacing the colon with a space).

Comment: illegal only, if you want to use it as part of a filename. (You also should mention `%date%` to make the answer complete)